# Logic Confusing Problem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I Read one logic book, can my two conclusion are true?

1- Suppose

[image]

for each valuation v, we have such n that

[image]

> > can we say we have such n that
> >
> > [image]

2- Suppose

[image]

for each valuation v, we have such n that

[image]

can we say  set {φ1,φ1∨φ2,φ1∨ φ2∨φ3,...} is consistent?

i think the (2) is not always true?  for (1) and (2) any description?

Comment: My interpretations of the question are: Let $\varphi _1, \ldots ,\varphi_n$ be well formed formulas and set $\Sigma=\{\varphi _1, \ldots ,\varphi_n\}$. Suppose that for all valuations $v$ (alternatively suppose that some valuation $v$) it holds that $v(\varphi_n)=1$. Does $\models \Sigma$ follow? *Do you mean any of these? Which?*

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: $\huge{-\space\_\_-}$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: i'm not familiar with MathJax, would you please use MathJax to edit?

Comment: Regarding your last edition, **if** $v(\varphi_n)=1$ but $n > 1$, then it is possible that $v(\varphi_1)=0$; if this is the case, clearly the set of formulae containing $\varphi_1$ is **not** consistent.

Comment: Dear @MauroALLEGRANZA, so you means (1) is correct always but (2) is not? am i right?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, Maybe for part (1) there is no such n. so it's not always true ?

Comment: Yes; for (2), it is not always true that the set of formulae is consistent.

Comment: Dear @MauroALLEGRANZA, the result of this question is (1) always true but (2) is not. thanks.

Comment: Dear @MauroALLEGRANZA, would you please comment on another solution that submited today.

Comment: I've re-edited my answer; we can agree with @AmHsnSharafi's answer. **Question 1** : according to my interpretation of the question, we cannot conclude with $\vDash \varphi_1 \lor ... \lor \varphi_n$. **Question 2** : according to your suggestion that $\varphi_1$ can be contradiction, then the condition of the question is not enough to conclude that the set of formulae is consistent.

Comment: Dear @MauroALLEGRANZA, in the question (2010 midterm exam on Poland University) not mentioned anything about consistency or non-consistency of Σ. if we suppose question (2) havent a contradiction, is always true?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think 1 is true, by applying compactness theorem you can show that 1 is true

Comment: Dear user, would you please proof it?

Comment: I proof it, if you want i send it to your email

Comment: please submit it to my email : hf9852@gmail.com

Comment: dear user, i send it to your email, please check it.

Answer (score 3):

*This is a logic "confused" problem ...*

We approach it "by steps".

*Question 1*

We assume that the meaning of the first part of the question is :

> for a *valuation* $v$ there is some $n$ for which : $v(\varphi_n)=1$.

Is so, due to the fact that : $v(\varphi_1 \lor \ldots \lor \varphi_n) = max_i \{ v(\varphi_i) \}$, we have that for the *valuation* $v$ :

> $v(\varphi_1 \lor \ldots \lor \varphi_n) = 1$.

*Conclusion* : if for a valuation $v$ there is a formula $\varphi_n$ such that $v(\varphi_n)=1$, then the *conjunction* $φ_1 \lor φ_2 \lor \ldots \lor φ_n$ is *consistent* (or *satisfiable*).

The symbol :

> > $\vDash \varphi_1 \lor \ldots \lor \varphi_n$

means that the formula $\varphi_1 \lor \ldots \lor \varphi_n$ is *valid* (or a *tautology*).

The above formula is valid when we have $v(\varphi_1 \lor \ldots \lor \varphi_n) = 1$ for **all** valuation $v$.

*Comclusion* : the fact that for every valuation $v$ there is a $n$ such that ... does not implies that there is an $n$ such that for every valuation $v$ ...

In other terms, the condition :

> for a *valuation* $v$ there is some $n$ for which : $v(\varphi_n)=1$.

is not enough to conclude with $\vDash \varphi_1 \lor \ldots \lor \varphi_n$.

---

*Question 2*

Assuming a set $\Sigma = \{ φ_1, φ_2, \ldots \}$ of formulae, if $\Sigma$ is *consistent*, then :

> $\Gamma = \{ φ_1, φ_1∨φ_2, φ_1∨φ_2∨φ_3, \ldots \}$ is always *consistent*.

Being $\Sigma$ consistent, there is a valuation $v$ such that $v(\varphi_i)=1$, for all $i$.

Thus :

> $v(φ_1)=v(φ_1∨φ_2)=v(φ_1∨φ_2∨φ_3) = \ldots=1$

i.e. the valuation $v$ satisfy **all** the formulae in $\Gamma$ and thus $\Gamma$ is *consistent*.

If $\Sigma$ is **not** consistent, this means that for each valuation $v$ there is a formula $\varphi_i$ such that $v(\varphi_i)=0$; but it is enough that $i > 1$ and $\Gamma$ will be still consistent.

In fact, if for the valuation $v_0$, $v_0(\varphi_1)=1$, then again :

> > $v_0(φ_1)=v_0(φ_1∨φ_2)=v_0(φ_1∨φ_2∨φ_3) = \ldots=1$.

**If** the formula $\varphi_1$ is *unsatisfiable* (e.g. a contradiction, like : $p \land \lnot p$) then for each valuation $v$, $v(\varphi_1)=0$; in this case, the set $\Gamma$ is **not** consistent.

By *Compactness Theorem* a set $\Gamma$ of formulae is consistent **iff** every *finite* subset of $\Gamma$ is consistent; thus, if $\{ \varphi_1 \} \subseteq \Gamma$ is not consistent, also $\Gamma$ is not.

Comment: Dear Mauro, can we say for each set {$\varphi_1$,$\varphi_1$$\lor$$\varphi_2$,$\varphi_1$$\lor$  $\varphi_2$$\lor$$\varphi_3$,...} is consistent?

Comment: infact one of this sentence should be true. 1) i mentioned in the question. and 2) one i mentioned in the comment? are you sure that both of them is true? thanks

Comment: i edit my question again. sorry.

Comment: i'm sorry for lots of question. i think, consider sigma = {p^~p, p∨~p,...} which p^~p = φ1, p∨~p=φ2,... so the φ1 is always false and as a result (Question2) is false.

Comment: @user153695 - of course...; **if** the $\varphi_i$ are **not** "independent" and you set as $\varphi_1$ a formula like $p \land \lnot p$ which is not satisfiable, obviously every set of formulae containing $\varphi_1$ will be *unsatisfiable* (i.e. not *consistent*).

Comment: you means with this observation, question 1 and question 2 is not always true?

Comment: i more clarify the question. i'm sorry. it's final version.

Comment: Dear @MMauro, would you please correct the answer according to question? i edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

Both of them are false, this is due to exact definition:

1.for a formula $\psi$ we say $\vDash\psi$ if for all valuations $w$, $w(\psi)=1$ not for just a valuation $v$.

2.We say a set is consistent if we could find a valuation $v$ such that for all formula $\psi$ in it $v(\psi)=1$. But as you said formula $\varphi_1$ could be a contradiction.

Comment: Dear AmHsnSharafi, Are u sure?

Comment: yes, But perhaps we didn't understand your mean from question well

Comment: Dear @AAmHsnSharafi, would you please correct the answer according to question? i edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you changed the question, first question is false yet because perhaps for each valuation $v$ only $v(\varphi_{n+1})=1$. But if you define $\Sigma=\{\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n\}$ your proposition would be true.

Even you defined $\Sigma=\{\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n\}$ (and you must do it because $\varphi_1\vee\varphi_2\vee\ldots$ is meaningless) your second question would be false since for all valuation $v$ it can be $v(\varphi_2)=1$ and $v(\varphi_1)=0$.

If you want your second proposition be true, after you defined $\Sigma=\{\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n\}$ you should change it:

For all formula $\varphi_k$ there is a valuation $v$ such that $v(\varphi_k)=1$

Comment: you means 1 and 2 now is false?

Comment: yes, you should do as I told